# Verify a CString like "-2-2" or "--22" or "2--2" is not a valid

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

In C++ how to verify a CString like "-2-2" or "--22" or "2--2" is not a valid integer.

I tried the following code :

```
// CString input in the edit box that needs to be verified
   CString input_to_editbox
// verify its a number or not
   if (input_to_editbox.SpanIncluding(L"-0123456789") == input_to_editbox)
   //numeric
   AfxMessageBox(L"it is an integer");
   else
   //Non numeric
   AfxMessageBox(L"Not an integer");
```

But I am not able to verify that "-2-2" or "--22" or "2--2"  is illegal and bad integer.

Comment: For a standard string, I'd run [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) on it and verify (via the second parameter `str_end`) that the whole string got parsed. Don't know my way around the Windows API's though; is there something similar for `CString`?

Comment: Verify that the first character is `'-'` or a digit and that all the rest are digits (`std::isdigit`).

Comment: @molbdnilo: and that it contains at least one digit.

Comment: With Regular Expressions ?  (ex with deelx.h)

Comment: Just check `if(input_to_editbox..ReverseFind(_T('-')) !=0)` //invalid result

Comment: `bool is_valid(string s) { return !(s=="-2-2" || s=="--22" || "2--2"); }`

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same problem when using the DDX_ functions which are not very strict regarding their input. I have resolved that with scanf (or better _stscanf_s).

```
int nValue;
unsigned charsRead = 0;
const int fieldsRead = _stscanf_s(str, _T("%d%n"), &nValue, &charsRead);
if(fieldsRead == 1  &&  charsRead == _tcslen(str)) {
    // We have read all fields and we have read the complete string,
    // so str contains a valid pattern.
}
```

You can easily adjust that method if you want to read other types (e.g. "%u%n") or multiple values (e.g. "rate is: %d/%d Mbits/s%n"). Just don't forget to compare fieldsRead to the right value.